# Unable to convert RelativeLayout to ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-relativelayout

I have the following code and I want to convert the RelativeLayout to be ConstraintLayout and want it to show exactly the same. However, The ViewPager tag doesn't settle in the center like expected. I want the following code to be in constraint layout but unable to achive it. I converted layout_above to layout_constraintTop_toTopOf and such but cannot make it work well. It would be lovely if you can share me some examples or tips! I would love to hear from you !

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

                <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/d"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <View android:layout_width="0dp"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:layout_height="1dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@id/footer"
                android:layout_below="@id/header"
                android:overScrollMode="never">
        </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/footer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:orientation="vertical">
            <include layout="@layout/pagerlayout"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Tip: the equivalent of `layout_above` is probably `layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf` rather than `layout_constraintTop_toTopOf`. If that doesn't help, then you'll need to post your current attempt :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a ConstraintLayout template with header and footer with a viewpager in between, then here ya go:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/footer"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/footer"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/header"></androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
        <!-- include layout="@layout/pagerlayout"/ -->

    </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

You should be able to start from there and acheive what you want.

If you ask any follow up questions, they will be ignored because your question has so little information included that if would be unfair to do so.